# Error while using JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());

Tags: java, swing

I'm having a problem when i try to use:

```
JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance());
```

I get an error that the number I put in is wrong when I put a number in to a number box because there is a space between a number, like this: `200 000` and when the number is `200000` I get no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `MaskFormatter` as described in [How to use Formatted Text Field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) in order to avoid getting non-digit characters:

```
    JFormattedTextField textField = new JFormattedTextField(new MaskFormatter("#######"));
```

However, if you use this way, when you will copy paste the text `200 000`, it will either not be pasted or only 200 will be pasted. (The rest after the space - non digit character will be ignored)

In order to allow this you will have to use [a Document Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) that keeps only the digits. So when the input will come with space `200 000` it will keep `200000`:

```
class NumberOnlyDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr)
            throws BadLocationException {
        super.insertString(fb, offset, keepOnlyDigits(string), attr);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
            throws BadLocationException {
        super.replace(fb, offset, length, keepOnlyDigits(text), attrs);
    }

    private String keepOnlyDigits(String text) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : text.toCharArray())
            if (Character.isDigit(c))
                sb.append(c);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And to "install" it:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
AbstractDocument document = (AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument();
document.setDocumentFilter(new NumberOnlyDocumentFilter());
```